# How to replace text in multiple files and save each in new folder using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with multiple files. I want to read each file and replace  with whatever the user passes to the application (a parameter). After the content of the file is replaced, I want to save the file in a new folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
gci C:\Users\Person\Documents\Test1\*.bat -recurse | ForEach {
  (Get-Content $_ | ForEach {$_ -replace "<client_instance>", "ClientName"}) | Set-Content $_ 
}
```

My first question is, is this correct and secondly, how do I change "Set-Content" so that it saves the files in a different folder?

I want to use variables for the source and destination:

```
$sourePath
$destinationPath
```

I'm new to PowerShell so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is fine. You can build your new path like this:

```
$files = gci C:\Users\Person\Documents\Test1\*.bat -recurse
$destinationpath = "C:\users\person\documents\test2"
ForEach ($file in $files){
    Get-Content $file.fullname | ForEach {$_ -replace "<client_instance>", "ClientName"} | set-content "$destinationpath\$($file.basename)"
}
```

You might have to tweak it here and there to fit your needs.

Comment: this worked. thank you. i just had to add ".bat" for the destination file type. i can accept your answer in 3 mins.

Comment: Why is changing to `Out-File` required?  You could just as easily do `Set-Content "$destinationpath\$($file.basename)"`.  The major point is that `Get-Content $_ | ... | Set-Content $_` overwrites the source file.

Comment: I definitely don't want to replace the original file. I want to create a copy with the replaced values.

Comment: @BACON You're completely right, I've somehow taken "change set-content" literally. Edited my answer to be more concise what had to be changed.

Comment: @RJ. Right.  The problem with the `Set-Content $_` that you used is not `Set-Content` but the value passed for the `-Path` parameter, `$_`.